# symfony php- where is controller - model reference is defined

Tags: symfony

in what file, or where ,is the mapping of controller to model occur in

1. symfony 1.4
2. symfony 2

are there any yml/config files that tell the system to recognize the appropriate model?

what I mean is:
let's say a controller looks like this:

```
class jobActions extends sfActions
{
     public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
     {
       $user=new PcUser();
       $user->username=$request->GetParameters(...);
     }
}
```

and PcUser.php is an entity file that has PcUser class inside.
where is the mapping done? how does the controller jobActions know PcUser?

Comment: Have you tried the [official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)?

Comment: This is the role of [autoloading](http://phpmaster.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done by symfony's autoloader. If the script doesn't know about class you are trying to use, then autoloader try include appropriate class based on namespace.

So, for your example:

```
class SomeController
{
     public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
     {
         $user=new \NamespaceForBundle\Entity\PcUser();
         $user->username=$request->GetParameters(...);
     }
}
```

And if you ask about ORM mapping - you can do it in several ways like appropriate yaml configuration file, or annotations inside entities.